# Need to know about " . " Symbol?

Tags: syntax

There is a command

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
```

I need to know why there is "." right before ~/.bashrc?

Comment: @Tshilidzi please don't edit closed questions which are unlikely to get re-opened. That just wastes reviewers' time: http://askubuntu.com/review/reopen/675451

Comment: Hi @muru, I didn't know, now I know, thanks.